# Unity Record Video and Take Screenshot

Tags: ios, video, unity-game-engine

I am using webCamTexture to capture my device back camera. What I would like to do is, take a screenshot (which works) and right after that I want to capture a 5 second video, without hitting a play button or anything. It should just start right after making the screenshot.
I tried the plugin Camera shot, which works, but I need to click a button to start the video. After that I tried unitys everyplay plugin.
Which also works fine, but I only makes a video without sound and also I don't know how to get the path where the video was saved.

Is there maybe another way of capturing a video right away and to define the path.
The app should run on ios.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am late but there's the code for getting the video path in Everyplay.

```
void WalkSessions()
{
  Debug.Log ("Walking sessions");
  string basePath = Application.temporaryCachePath;
  #if UNITY_ANDROID
  string[] sParts = basePath.Split('/');
  basePath = "/sdcard/Android/data/"+sParts[sParts.Length-2]+"/cache/sessions/";
  #elif UNITY_IOS
  basePath = basePath.Substring (0,basePath.Length-15);
  basePath += "/tmp/Everyplay/session/";
  #endif
  string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories (basePath);
  foreach (string s in dirs) {
    Debug.Log ("Found folder: " + s);
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (s);
    Debug.Log ("It contains the following files:");
    foreach(string s2 in files)
      Debug.Log (s2);
    }
  }
}
```

After, you can handle the video for what ever you want. Share your code and I will help you out... I think you can easily achieve what you want by tweaking Everyplay codes and a coroutine.

I hope this helps!